# python matplotlib plotfile explicitly use floating number

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a simple data file to plot.

Here is the contents of a data file and I named it "ttry":

```
  0.27                   0
  0.28                   0
  0.29                   0
   0.3                   0
  0.31                   0
  0.32                   0
  0.33                   0
  0.34                   0
  0.35                   0
  0.36                   0
  0.37                   0
  0.38    0.00728737997257
  0.39     0.0600137174211
   0.4       0.11488340192
  0.41      0.157321673525
  0.42      0.193158436214
  0.43      0.233882030178
  0.44      0.273319615912
  0.45      0.311556927298
  0.46      0.349879972565
  0.47      0.387602880658
  0.48      0.424211248285
  0.49      0.460390946502
   0.5      0.494855967078
  0.51      0.529406721536
  0.52      0.561814128944
  0.53      0.594307270233
  0.54      0.624228395062
  0.55      0.654492455418
  0.56      0.683984910837
  0.57      0.711762688615
  0.58      0.739368998628
  0.59      0.765775034294
   0.6      0.790895061728
  0.61      0.815586419753
  0.62      0.840192043896
  0.63      0.863082990398
  0.64      0.886231138546
  0.65      0.906292866941
  0.66      0.915809327846
  0.67      0.911436899863
  0.68      0.908179012346
  0.69      0.904749657064
   0.7      0.899519890261
  0.71      0.895147462277
  0.72      0.891632373114
  0.73      0.888803155007
  0.74      0.884687928669
  0.75      0.879029492455
  0.76      0.876114540466
  0.77      0.872170781893
  0.78      0.867541152263
  0.79       0.86274005487
   0.8      0.858367626886
  0.81      0.854080932785
  0.82      0.850994513032
  0.83      0.997170781893
  0.84       1.13477366255
  0.85       1.24296982167
  0.86       1.32690329218
  0.87       1.40397805213
  0.88       1.46836419753
  0.89       1.52306241427
   0.9       1.53232167353
  0.91       1.52906378601
  0.92       1.52211934156
  0.93         1.516718107
  0.94       1.51543209877
  0.95       1.50660150892
  0.96       1.50137174211
  0.97       1.49408436214
  0.98       1.48816872428
  0.99       1.48088134431
     1        1.4723079561
```

And then I use matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile to plot it. Here is my python script

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.plotfile("ttry", cols=(0,1), delimiter=" ")
pyplot.show()
```

However the following error appears:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ttry.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\research\ttry.py", line 2, in <module>
pyplot.plotfile("ttry",col=(0,1),delimiter=" ")
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2311, in plotfile
checkrows=checkrows, delimiter=delimiter, names=names)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2163, in csv2rec
rows.append([func(name, val) for func, name, val in zip(converters, names, row)])
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2163, in <listcomp>
rows.append([func(name, val) for func, name, val in zip(converters, names, row)])
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 2031, in newfunc
return func(val)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00728737997257'
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Obviously, python just considers yaxis data as int. So how to tell python I use float for yaxis data?

Comment: You've got some `0`s in the y column at first, have you tried changing them to floats? I.e. `0.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implies `int` type of your second column based on first few values, which are all `int`'s. To make it check all rows, add `checkrows = 0` to arguments, that is:

```
pyplot.plotfile("ttry", cols=(0,1), delimiter=" ", checkrows = 0)
```

It's an argument coming from `matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec`, see more info [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec).